# RPM build fails locating libelf.so.dts.1 when using Developer Toolset 7

Tags: rpmbuild, devtoolset

I am compiling software for Red Hat/CentOS 7 (running on CentOS) using the compiler from  [Developer Toolset 7](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/), and when I try to create an RPM, rpmbuild fails with the following error:

```
+ /usr/lib/rpm/find-debuginfo.sh --strict-build-id -m --run-dwz --dwz-low-mem-die-limit 10000000 --dwz-max-die-limit 110000000 /home/peter/src/foo/rpmbuild/BUILD/mypackage-5.4.0_10_243_g2564bd2ee3
extracting debug info from /home/peter/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/mypackage-5.4.0_10_243_g2564bd2ee3-1.x86_64/path/to/my/bin/binary
eu-strip: error while loading shared libraries: libelf.so.dts.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I did not see this using Toolset 3, and basically all I did was to change the 3 in my build script to a 7.

*EDIT:* If I  disable extraction of debug information (`%define debug_package %{nil}`), I do not get the error.

Comment: I get this error when compiling the kernel.